# Перспективу можно раскинуть?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Они ухаживали за мной давно, как-то по-ремарковски и наперегонки.
>   Упражнялись в остроумии, предупредительности, сыпали заманчивыми
>   предложениями, **раскидывали восхитительные перспективы**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь пара сочетаний: ***сыпали*** заманчивыми предложениями, **раскидывали** восхитительные перспективы.

**Переносное значение** для глагола ***сыпать*** уже встречается (*сыпать деньгами*), а *раскидывать перспективы*  имеет примерно тот же смысл, но не является общепринятым.

Поэтому можно заключить слово в кавычки, чтобы оставить авторскую пару выражений.

СЫПАТЬ, 1. что. Заставлять постепенно падать (что-л. сыпучее, мелкое). С. муку в мешок. С. соль в суп. // **что или чем.** **Бросать, ронять, разбрасывать** (что-л. сыпучее, мелкое). С. крошки на скатерть. С. пыль. С. искры. С. брызги. **С. песком** в кого-л. **С. деньгами** (=сорить деньгами).

Comment: Кавычки - ни за что! Хочу, чтоб было можно: раскидывали. И - зачем нам что-то общепринятое?!

Comment: Тогда читатели должны сами услышать эту пару. Мне кажется. что это не трудно.

Comment: "Сыпать предложениями" - корректное выражение; если же заключить в кавычки второе, создастся впечатление, что автор не смог подобрать более подходящее слово и остановился на пришедшем в голову.

Comment: Кавычки уже убрали. Я же сказала, что можно, но вовсе не обязательно. Вот и решили, что они лишние.

Answer (score 1):

Спокойнее "*расписывали*": раскинуть подобно скатерти можно лишь то, чем располагает сам "раскидывающий". Перспектива же может либо сама *раскинуться* перед внутренним взором индивида (аналогия с уходящей к горизонту дорогой), либо быть *физически раскинутой* кем-то в виде *изображения*, существующего на сложенном холсте, свёрнутом ковре и т. п. Видимо, поэтому выражение и вызывает серьёзные сомнения.

Answer (score 1):

[перспекти́ва](http://rus-gos.spbu.ru/index.php/words/show/11961), -ы; ж. [франц. perspective]
5. То, что должно или может произойти, наступить вслед за настоящим, дальнейший ход каких‑л. событий.   // обычно мн.: перспекти́вы, -ти́в. **Виды, планы на будущее.**
*Перспективы дальнейшего развития. Перспективы работы. Перспективы женитьбы. Начать, рисовать, **раскинуть перспективы.***
(Большой толковый словарь русского языка под ред. С. А. Кузнецова)

Comment: Римулечка, огромное Вам мерси. А Вы на Лорочку откликаетесь иль как? О_о